# Automatically Load Grid after adding data using Modal Window Ext JS

Tags: extjs

I'm new in Ext Js and I have a Grid and trying to insert new data using the Modal Window. The Grid should automatically refresh after data has been input or save into the store.

**Customer Model**

```
Ext.define('Customer', {
    extend: 'model.Base',
    alias :  'Customer',

    fields: [
        { name : 'id', type :'int', persist : false },
        { name : 'first_name', type : 'string'},
        { name : 'last_name', type : 'string'},
        { name : 'birthday', type : 'date',  dateWriteFormat:'Y-m-d'},
        { name : 'phone_no', type : 'string'},
        { name : 'email', type : 'string'},
        { name : 'username', type : 'string'},
        { name : 'password', type : 'string'},
    ],
});
```

**Customer Store**

```
Ext.define('Customer', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.customer',
    model: 'model.Customer',
    pageSize : 25,
    id : 'customerId',
    autoSave : false,
    autoSync : false,

    require :[
        'model.Customer'
    ],

    proxy:{
        type: 'rest',
        enablePaging : true,
        batchActions : true,
        api :{
            read: '/api/Customer/pagination/',
            create: '/api/Customer/',
            update: '/api/Customer/',
            destroy: '/api/Customer/',
        },

        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'Customer',
            totalProperty : 'TotalCount'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            dateFormat: 'Y-m-d',
            // writeAllFields: false,
        },

        listeners: {
            exception: function(proxy, response, operation, eOpts) {
                if(response.responseJson.Message){
                    this.showToast(response.responseJson.Message);
                }
            },
        },

        showToast: function(s) {     
            Ext.toast({
                html: s,
                closable: false,
                align: 't',
                slideDUration: 400,
                maxWidth: 400
            });
        },
    },
});
```

**Customer ViewModel**

```
Ext.define('CustomerViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.customer',
    deep : true,

    data: {
        userData : null,
    },

    stores :{
        customerStore :{
            type : 'customer'
        },
    },
});
```

**Customer Controller**

```
Ext.define('CustomerController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.customer',

    //
    showAddForm : function(){
        var form = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('AddCustomer')[0];
        if (!form) {
            form = Ext.create('VidlyApp.view.customer.AddCustomer');
        }
        if (form.isHidden()) {
            form.show();
        }
    },

    onAddCustomer : function(){
        var me = this;
        var viewmodel  = me.getViewModel();
        var store  = viewmodel.get('customerStore');
        store.add(viewmodel.data.userData);
        // store.insert( 0,viewmodel.data.userData);
        store.sync({
            success: function(response, request) {
                me.showToast("Account Successfully Created!");
                me.getView().destroy();
            },
            failure :function(response){
                store.rejectChanges();
                me.showToast("Operation Failed! Something went wrong!");
            }
        });
    },

    showToast: function(s) {
        Ext.toast({
            html: s,
            closable: false,
            align: 't',
            slideDUration: 400,
            maxWidth: 400
        });
    }

});
```

**Customer List - View**

```
Ext.define('CustomerList', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'customerlist',
    controller: 'customer',
    title: 'Customer',
    width : '99%',
    height: 700,
    border : 1,

    requires: [
        'VidlyApp.store.Customer',
        'Ext.grid.column.Action',
        'Ext.toolbar.Paging',
    ],

    viewModel: {
        type : 'customer',
    },

    bind : {
        store: '{customerStore}',
    },


    columns: [
        { xtype: 'rownumberer' },
        { text: 'id',  dataIndex: 'id' },
        { text: 'First Name',  dataIndex: 'first_name', flex : 1 },
        { text: 'Last Name',  dataIndex: 'last_name',  flex : 1},
        { text: 'Birthday',  dataIndex: 'birthday', formatter: 'date("m/d/Y")' },
        { text: 'Phone No.', dataIndex: 'phone_no',  flex : 1},
        { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email',  flex : 1},
        { text: 'Username', dataIndex: 'username',  flex : 1},
        { text: 'Password', dataIndex: 'password' },
        {
            text: 'Actions',
            xtype:'actioncolumn',
            width:100,
            items: [{
                icon: 'EditIcon.png',
                tooltip: 'Edit',
                handler : 'showEditForm'
            },{
                icon: 'deleteIcon,png',
                tooltip: 'Delete',
                handler : 'onDeleteCustomer'
            }]
        }
    ],
});
```

**AddCustomer (Modal Window) - View**

```
Ext.define('AddCustomer', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.AddCustomer' ,
    controller : 'customer',
    title: 'Add Customer',
    autoDestroy: false,
    viewModel : 'customer',

    items: [
        {
            xtype : 'form',
            reference: 'form',
            layout : 'vbox',
            bodyPadding:20, 
            width:400,
            height:500,
            default :{
                width:400,
                height:500,
            },
            defaultType: 'textfield',
            items: [{
                fieldLabel: 'First Name',
                bind: '{userData.first_name}',
                allowBlank:false,
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                bind: '{userData.last_name}',
                allowBlank:false,
            }, {
                xtype: 'datefield',
                format: 'Y-m-d',
                fieldLabel: 'Birth Date',
                bind: '{userData.birthday}',
                maxValue: new Date(),
                allowBlank:false,
            }, {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Phone No',
                bind: '{userData.phone_no}',
                allowBlank:false,
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'Email',
                bind: '{userData.email}',
                vtype: 'email',
                allowBlank:false,
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'Username',
                bind: '{userData.username}',
                allowBlank:false,
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'Password',
                bind: '{userData.password}',
                inputType : 'password',
                allowBlank:false,
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'Confirm Password',
                bind: '{userData.confirm_password}',
                inputType : 'password',
                allowBlank:false,
            },
        ],

            buttons: [{
                text: 'Add',
                formBind: true,
                listeners: {
                    click : 'onAddCustomer'
                }
            }],
        }
    ],

    listeners:{
        close: 'close',
    },
});
```

Please help me. TIA.

Automatically Load Grid after adding Data using Modal Window.

Answer (score 0):

Reload the store after the sync is completed, this should refresh the grid contents:

```
 store.sync({
            success: function(response, request) {
                me.showToast("Account Successfully Created!");
                // add this:
                store.reload();
                me.getView().destroy();
            },
            failure :function(response){
                store.rejectChanges();
                me.showToast("Operation Failed! Something went wrong!");
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried but still not working.  As you can see, I also put reload inside the success function but still nothing happens.

Comment: I don't see where you put reload, but `me.getView().destroy();` will destroy the grid. Try to remove it.

Comment: Is the record created on the server side? If you load it again, do you see it in the grid?

Comment: To clarify I have to 2 sepetate views which is the Grid and Modal Window (pop-up form).

I used `me.getView().destroy();` to close the Modal Window (pop-up form) once the data is created. 

The grid won't load but once I load the web or click the load button on my server-side pagination the data shows up.

Comment: If you pause the code in `success`, and you type `store.reload()` to the console, do you see activity on the network tab of devtools?

Comment: I solved the problem by adding `form.getViewModel().set('customerStore' ,this.getViewModel().getStore('customerStore'));` when opening the Modal Window. So that they have the same instance of store with the Grid.

Answer (score 0):

The Modal Window has no parent component and as such does not inherit the ViewModel that maintains the initial data you're working with. If you want the data to be part of the modal window, you can either add the Modal Window to the parent component (i.e. make it not a floating component that has the document.body as its owner) or pass the ViewModel or a data session to the modal window. There is an example in the Kitchen Sink that elaborates on this use case with isolated child session and might give you some ideas: https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/examples/kitchensink/?profile=modern-triton#binding-child-session